# How does making a locker object static affect its behavior?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

Let's say I have a class with a member that looks like this:

```
readonly object _locker;
```

which I use to synchronize blocks of code like this:

```
lock (_locker)
{
    // Do something

    Monitor.Pulse(_locker);
}
```

and this:

```
lock (_locker)
{
    while (someCondition)
        Monitor.Wait(_locker);

    // Do something else
}
```

Let's say that I have multiple instances of this particular class, all running at the same time, using separate threads.

What happens to the behavior of the locks and the `Monitor.Wait` and `Monitor.Pulse` calls if I make the locker object `static`?

```
static readonly object _locker;
```

Do they all suddenly start working in lockstep (e.g.  locking a block of code takes a `lock` across all instances of the object), or is there no change in behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By making the `_locker` static you create 1 shared critical region. Yes, they will all wait for each other. That is sensible and necessary when your shared data is also static.

If the shared data is per-instance, then don't make the  `_locker` static.

In other words, it depends on what the real code for `// Do something else` is.

Comment: Most of the code examples I've seen use the `static` keyword, so I guess that kind of threw me.

Comment: Both forms are used, it entirely depends on the data.

Answer (score 2):

The object will be shared between all instances, and so each object will block if they try to acquire the lock and any other object has it.